# Has anyone worked out how to manually add labels into a Core-Plot (iPhone) graph?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, core-plot, label

I have a simply bar graph created for my iPhone application however I want to manually add the x-axis labels.  Has anyone worked out a way to do this?

I found the CPXYAxisSet.xAxis.axisLabels property however when I create an NSSet and assign it using:

```
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabelingPolicy = CPAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
NSSet *labels = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"year 1", @"year 2" @"year 3", nil];
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels = labels;
```

I get a:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'expecting model layer not copy: year 1'
```

error.

Anyone have a solution?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this [has been addressed](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/msg/9a2322db73efda01?hl=en) in the [Core Plot mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss?hl=en).  The axisLabels property takes in a set of CPAxisLabel objects (a descendant of CALayer), not NSStrings, which is why you're getting the above exception.

To create a CPAxisLabel for each of your custom labels, use code similar to the following:

```
CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: customText]; 
newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue]; 
newLabel.textStyle = x.axisLabelTextStyle; 
newLabel.offset = x.axisLabelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
```

EDIT (1/18/2010): An example of this is now present in the Core Plot iPhone test application, under the bar chart tab.

Comment: Many thanks.  I'll also take the hint and head over ot the Core Plot mailing list :-)

Comment: No problem. I'm just one of the few contributors with an account here, so you'll probably get more eyeballs on an issue there.